# tsconfig error when encountering = inside <>

Tags: typescript, tsc

When I run tsc, I get the following error

```
export type Handler<TEvent = any, TResult = any> = (
                           ~
functions/node_modules/@types/aws-lambda/index.d.ts(600,28): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

**Note:** It shows error for the TEvent = any code

This is my compiler options

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
        "dom",
        "dom.iterable",
        "scripthost",
        "es2015.promise",
        "es2015",
        "es6",
        "es2016",
        "es7"
    ],
    "watch": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "newLine": "LF",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "sourceMap": false
},
```

The errors are in the index.d.ts files of many imported libraries

The typescript version is 2.8.3

Comment: i can't change it as it is in aws-lambda library

Comment: What's your typescript version? Generic parameter defaults were added in typescript version [2.3](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html)

Comment: it is 2.8.3. I upgraded to latest version